# Among 26 natural numbers from $\{1,2,3,...,100\}$ there are at least $2$ integers whose difference is atmost $3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The heading says the question. Is it true that we can find 2 integers with their difference atmost 3 ?

I have taken pairs with difference $3$ and after that kind of lost.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you fit in 26 eith difference at least 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint pigeonhole

$100 \div 4$

..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1506508)

Comment: @Anonymous I wasn't aware that a Hint - Answer violated protocol.  I am not providing a solution.  The hint leaves the OP with thinking and work to do.  This is a fairly common practice on mathSE.  I have never seen anything that suggested that providing a Hint/Answer was a violation of mathSE protocol.  Am I mistaken about whether I have violated protocol?

Comment: You have not violated any protocol, instead this answer can be easily posted as a comment and does not feel to be an answer.

Comment: @Anonymous "and does not feel to be an answer" Reasonable point but subjective.  I feel differently.

Comment: It's little bit strange but this hint kind of gave a good visualisation of the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Among $3$ natural numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ there are at least $2$ integers whose difference is at most $3$. Do you believe this? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose , not then there exist $a_{1}\leq a_{2}\leq ...\leq a_{26}$ such that $a_{j+1}-a_{j}\geq 4$ for $j=1,2,...,25$
Then $a_{26}-a_{1}=\sum_{j=1}^{25} a_{j+1}-a_{j}\geq 100$
But we know $a_{26}-a_{1}\leq 99$ since it's belongs to that set $\{1,2,..,100\}$.This possible contradiction leads to the solution.